# search an array of tags with mongoid search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using mongoid search to search the title and description of images people upload. I also want to search an array of tags, since people are giving these images tags. I'm using the gem mongoid_taggable to create the tags, which get's stored in an array and I'm using mongoid_search to search the array.

mongoid_search indexed everything but the tags and I don't know how to make it index the tags array.

```
search_in :title, :tags, :description, :designer => :name, :designer => :username

field :width
field :height
field :description, :type => String
field :title, :type => String
field :tags, type: Array
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend posting to the project's issues: https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search/issues

Comment: Do you think it's an issue in the gem? It's not something that I'm doing wrongly here? Do you know how it's done in other tag and search related gems. Have had a hard time finding this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out. The mongoid_taggable created a tags_array in the database, so I needed to do search_in :tags_array instead of search_in :tags.